# Extract sub arrays based on kernel in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to know if there is an efficient method to get sub-arrays from a larger `numpy` array.

What I have is an application of `np.where`. I iterate 'manually' over `x` and `y` as offsets and apply `where` with a kernel to each rectangle extracted from the larger array with proper dimensions.

But is there a more direct approach in `numpy`'s collection of methods?

```
import numpy as np

example = np.arange(20).reshape((5, 4))

# e.g. a cross kernel
a_kernel = np.asarray([[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]])

np.where(a_kernel, example[1:4, 1:4], 0)
# returns
# array([[ 0,  6,  0],
#        [ 9, 10, 11],
#        [ 0, 14,  0]])


def arrays_from_kernel(a, a_kernel):
    width, height = a_kernel.shape
    y_max, x_max = a.shape
    return [np.where(a_kernel, a[y:(y + height), x:(x + width)], 0)
            for y in range(y_max - height + 1)
            for x in range(x_max - width + 1)]


sub_arrays = arrays_from_kernel(example, a_kernel)
```

This returns the arrays I need for further processing.

```
# [array([[0, 1, 0],
#         [4, 5, 6],
#         [0, 9, 0]]),
#  array([[ 0,  2,  0],
#         [ 5,  6,  7],
#         [ 0, 10,  0]]),
#  ...
#  array([[ 0,  9,  0],
#         [12, 13, 14],
#         [ 0, 17,  0]]),
#  array([[ 0, 10,  0],
#         [13, 14, 15],
#         [ 0, 18,  0]])]
```

The context: similar to 2D convolution I would like to apply a custom function on each of the subarrays (e.g. product of squared numbers).

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, you're manually advancing a sliding window over the data - stride tricks to the rescue! (And no, I didn't just make that up - there's *actually* a submodule called `stride_tricks` in numpy!) Instead of manually building windows into the data, and calling `np.where()` on them, if you had the windows in an array, you could call `np.where()` just once. Stride tricks allow you to create such an array without even having to copy the data.

Let me explain. Normal slices in numpy create views into the original data instead of copies. This is done by referring to the original data, but changing the strides used to access the data (ie. how much to jump between two elements or two rows, and so on). Stride tricks allow you to modify those strides more freely than just slicing and reshaping does, so you can eg. iterate over the same data more than once, which is useful here.

Let me demonstrate:

```
import numpy as np

example = np.arange(20).reshape((5, 4))
a_kernel = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]])

def sliding_window(data, win_shape, **kwargs):
        assert data.ndim == len(win_shape)
        shape = tuple(dn - wn + 1 for dn, wn in zip(data.shape, win_shape)) + win_shape
        strides = data.strides * 2
        return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(data, shape=shape, strides=strides, **kwargs)

def arrays_from_kernel(a, a_kernel):
        windows = sliding_window(a, a_kernel.shape)
        return np.where(a_kernel, windows, 0)

sub_arrays = arrays_from_kernel(example, a_kernel)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`scipy.ndimage` module](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/ndimage.html) offers a number of filters -- one of which might meet your needs. If none of those filters do what you want, you could use [`ndimage.generic_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter)
to call a custom function on each subarray. `ndimage.generic_filter` is not as fast as the other `ndimage` filters, however.

For example,

```
import numpy as np

example = np.arange(20).reshape((5, 4))
a_kernel = np.asarray([[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]])

# def arrays_from_kernel(a, a_kernel):
#     width, height = a_kernel.shape
#     y_max, x_max = a.shape
#     return [np.where(a_kernel, a[y:(y + height), x:(x + width)], 0)
#             for y in range(y_max - height + 1)
#             for x in range(x_max - width + 1)]

# sub_arrays = arrays_from_kernel(example, a_kernel)
# for arr in sub_arrays:
#     print(arr)

# print('-'*80)

import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
def func(x):
    # reject subarrays that extend beyond the border of the `example` array
    if not np.isnan(x).any():
        y = np.zeros_like(a_kernel, dtype=example.dtype)
        np.put(y, np.flatnonzero(a_kernel), x)
        print(y)
    # Instead or returning 0, you can perform your desired computation on the subarray here.
    # Note that you may not need the 2D array y; often, you only need the values in the 1D array x
    return 0
result = ndimage.generic_filter(example, func, footprint=a_kernel, mode='constant', cval=np.nan)
```

---

For the particular problem of computing the product of squares for each subarray, you
could convert the product into a sum by taking advantage of the fact that `A * B = exp(log(A)+log(B))`. This would allow you to express the computation as a normal convolution. Now using `ndimage.convolve` can improve performance a lot. The amount of the improvement depends on the size of `example`:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
import perfplot

a_kernel = np.asarray([[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]])


def orig(example, a_kernel=a_kernel):
    def arrays_from_kernel(a, a_kernel):
        width, height = a_kernel.shape
        y_max, x_max = a.shape
        return [
            np.where(a_kernel, a[y : (y + height), x : (x + width)], 1)
            for y in range(y_max - height + 1)
            for x in range(x_max - width + 1)
        ]

    return [np.prod(x) ** 2 for x in arrays_from_kernel(example, a_kernel)]


def alt(example, a_kernel=a_kernel):
    logged = np.log(example)
    result = ndimage.convolve(logged, a_kernel, mode="constant", cval=0)[1:-1, 1:-1]
    return (np.exp(result) ** 2).ravel()


def make_example(N):
    return np.random.random(size=(N, N))


def check(A, B):
    return np.allclose(A, B)


perfplot.show(
    setup=make_example,
    kernels=[orig, alt],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(2, 11)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    xlabel="len(example)",
    equality_check=check,
)
```

[image]

Comment: This very nice, thank you! But it is slower than `%timeit [x.sum() for x in arrays_from_kernel(example, a_kernel)]` = 77.5 µs vs 205 µs (I used `def filter_func(x):
    if not np.isnan(x).any():
        return x.sum()
    return 0`)
(I used sum simply for timings)

Comment: @Drey: Yes, `generic_filter` may not offer better performance, but the difference in speed is not so different as `example` gets larger. For the particular calculation `x.sum()`, `ndimage.convolve` is much much faster than `[x.sum() for x in arrays_from_kernel(example, a_kernel)]`, but AFAICS for the product of squares you may need `generic_filter` (or `arrays_from_kernel`).

Comment: I added an alternative, `alt`, which is much faster than using `arrays_from_kernel` for the particular problem of computing the product of squares.